# Ember JS not rendering into nested outlet as expected when application contains named outlets

Tags: ember.js, nested, outlet

Given the following views:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <article>{{outlet "foo"}}</article>
    <aside>{{outlet}}</aside>
</script>


<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="base/index">
    <h2>Base</h2>
    {{view Ember.Select
        contentBinding=model
        optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.name"
        prompt="Select a child"
        valueBinding="selectedChild"}}

    <div id="child">
      <p>I want the child rendering here</p>
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foo">
    <h2>Foo</h2>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="child">
    <h2>Child</h2>
    <p>Child: {{id}} {{name}}</p>
    <pre>{{controller}}</pre>
</script>
```

And this app:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true,
    LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('base', function() {
        this.resource('child', {path: ':child_id'});
    });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function() {
        this.transitionTo('base');
    }
});

App.BaseRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('foo', {into: 'application', outlet: 'foo'});
    }
});

App.BaseIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return children;
    }
});

App.ChildController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();

App.BaseIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({ 
    selectedChild: null,

    selectedChildChanged: function() {
        var id = this.get('selectedChild');
        this.transitionToRoute('child', id);
    }.observes('selectedChild')

});

App.ChildRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return children[params.child_id - 1];
    }
});

var children = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Foo Goggins'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Bar McFudger'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Gia Goggins-McFudger'}
];
```

I'm expecting the child view to be rendered into the `{{outlet}}` inside the `div#child` however it renders into the main applications outlet instead.

You can see a working example here http://jsbin.com/docuj/10/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` route is an actual route under your resource, if you navigate deeper, that index route is replaced with the resource of the deeper route.  You'll want to move it from the `index` to just the resource route itself.

```
App.BaseRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
  model: function() {
    return children;
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this._super();

    this.render('foo', {into: 'application', outlet: 'foo'});
  }
});


App.BaseController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({ 
  selectedChild: null,

  selectedChildChanged: function() {
    var id = this.get('selectedChild');
    this.transitionToRoute('child', id);
  }.observes('selectedChild')

});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/vilimete/1/edit

Let's try and clear it up, underneath resources you can have resources or routes.  Routes can't have anything underneath them, they are a dead end street.  In this particular case, you weren't defining the base resource or template.  Ember was being kind and assuming you wanted a base template with just this in it `{{outlet}}` and then it was rendering the base index route into that outlet.  When you switched to the child resource it was rendering the child resource in the base outlet.

Here's an example that might paint a picture of what was happening.
http://jsbin.com/xiqajawa/1/edit

Comment: It is doing that but the root unnamed `{{outlet}}` not the `{{outlet}}` that is inside the `base` template. Which is what I want to happen.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I got mixed up on which one was rendering where, fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks that works, though I'm not 100% clear as to why it works. I'm pretty new to ember.

Comment: I added some additional info above to see if it clears it up for you.  If you have any specific question ask away.